What margin requirement should I pay for the option positions?
I want to establish the following positions:
Long 50 ABC jan 820 Calls @3
Long 50 ABC jan 675 Puts @4

What margin requirement should I pay for the option positions?

You're 'establishing' long option positions. This means that you won't have to hold a margin because you're the one with the option to exercise. Once you've bought the options the only way you'd have to pay something if there's an action on your side.
Also you never 'pay' a margin. You do have to hold the margin amount in your account (or be covered by available stock - at a reduced rate).

Assuming that your broker allows it, equity options and equity index options with more than nine months until expiration can be purchased on margin with an initial and maintenance margin requirement of 75% of the market value.
